# Retrieve Translated NavigationMenu Items metadata for Deployment?

Tags: translation, experience-bundle, navigation-menu

I have NavigationMenu items for which translations are in place in Translation Workbench. But every time i add new translations i need a way to deploy them through Metadata deployment. For now i need to import & Export from Sites builder Settings.

> I am looking for Retrieval of Translated NavigationMenu items so that
> i can deploy them through metadata every time.